# Insert data from array to html file

Tags: php, html, file, insert, fopen

I have a csv file, that i have to open and convert to array.
Then i have to open html file, insert this array to specific place and then save this file.
It is important that i have to have two files.
I am gonna show you my code.
create.php

```
    session_start();
    $file = 'people.csv';
    $html = 'sign.php';
    if(file_exists($file)) //here I convert csv file to array
    {
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            $array_line_full[] = $line;
        }
        fclose($handle);

        foreach ($array_line_full as $array) // here i try to send this data vie session to this file, but it doesn't work
        {
            $_SESSION['array'] = $array;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $array[0];
            $_SESSION['spec'] = $array[1];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $array[2];
            $_SESSION['num'] = $array[3];
//            include('sign.php');
//            $f = fopen($html, 'w');
//            fwrite($f, $_SESSION['array']);
//            fclose($f);
//            $res = file_get_contents('sign.php');

            $res = file_put_contents($html, $_SESSION['array']);
            $newFile = fopen($array[0].'_HTML.html', 'w');
            fwrite($newFile, $res);
            fclose($newFile);
            echo "fgbfbg\n";
        }
```

And there is my html file.
The important thing is that this file have to stay clear as much as it possible (I mean no php code as much as that possible)

```
<?php
    $array = $_SESSION['array'];
?>
<body>
<div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="color:#3b9ed5">
                            <div><?= $array[0] ?></div>
                            <div><?= $array[1] ?></div>
                                <div> <?= $array[2] ?></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
...
```

What can I do to add information from php file to html file in these exact places and than save file with this insert data not using JS (if it is possible)

P.S. I am not a native english speaker so I am sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, here is an example to do that:

create.php

```
//... prepare csv to array

//create html 
$output ='';
foreach($_SESSION['array'] as $data){
   $output .= '<div>'.$data.'</div>';
}
ob_start();
include 'html.php';
$cached = ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents('generated.html',$cached);
```

html.php

```
<body>
<div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:#3b9ed5">
        <?= $output ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

`ob_start();` & `ob_end_clean()` caches the output that is generated when including the html.php.

Then we can write the chached output into a file.

Comment: thank you, it's a little bit correct, 'cause i have to paste data to exact places
but in this case a just have this data

Comment: @Darya Its just an example how to cache output of a file. You can your html file, it will work also. What never will work is your use of `file_put_contents` & `fopen`. This answer here is the right way. Start from here and have fun.